# jQuery - offset().left delivers wrong values for floated elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have floated elements inside a nav tag. When I use the offset() function I get strange floating values for the positions, that are not correct. What is wrong here?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vo1b3e86/2/)

HTML

```
<div id="navi">
        <a class="logo" >NAVI</a>
        <nav>
            <a>Element A</a>
            <a>Element B</a>
            <a>Element C</a>
        </nav> 

    </div>

   <br><br>
   <input type="text" />
```

CSS

```
#navi {
height: 60px;
width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
background: lightgrey;
}

 .logo {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
a{
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

JS

```
$('a').eq(1).offset().left
```

Answer (score 0):

The offset is actually returning the correct value because your font, and thus your `nav`, does not line up perfectly in pixels.  Here's how to get the "real" `nav` width:

```
$("nav")[0].getBoundingClientRect().width
```

Add Element A's left offset to the `nav`'s width and you will find that the addition works perfectly.  The obvious discrepency is the 30px margin on the Element A, which is NOT included in Element A's offset, but is included in the `nav`'s width.  http://jsfiddle.net/vo1b3e86/4/

After subtracting 30px, you'll come up with the body's width.

If you want to remove the numbers to the right of the decimal, you could use one of these `Math` functions, depending what you want:

- `Math.round()` Will round to the nearest whole number
- `Math.floor()` Will round down
- `Math.ceil()` Will round down

Let me know if that makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case values were wrong, because a $(document).ready and a setTimeout fro the calculation was needed to get the right values.